# Methods of injecting text

Tags: php

I recently created an image that automatically changes depending on the time thanks to a PHP script. I'm now thinking about doing something but I'm not sure if it's possible.

I do have restrictions. I need this to work on a forum board so it means I have to have all scripting on a different server. I would Google how to do this but I'm not sure what to search hence the broad title. If someone could possibly tell me if it's possible and show a small example to get me on the right track, that'd be appreciated.

What I need to do is print text out onto the page. As I stated above, all the scripting needs to be on a different server as the forum doesn't allow for php and only basic HTML (similar to here). This means I can't use `include 'file.php';`.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO You have two options

1. Use HTML iframe element to embeed the external content (just give the external URL and the browser will handle the rest)
2. Call ajax request from javascript and inject the result into the DOM tree of the board.

Now that Your decision what suits You more.

Comment: `<iframe>` and `<script>` aren't basic HTML. Whatever you can use here, is the same on the forum board. Any other ideas?

Comment: What do You mean by 'aren't basic HTML', they both actually are. In this case, what is the list of 'basic' HTML tags You can use there ?

Comment: Both Stack Exchange and the forum board I've stated use Markdown. Markdown supports for only "basic HTML".

See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites